# Java not treating 0xFC as a signed integer?

Tags: java, unsigned

Just when I though I had a fair grasp on how Java treats all Integers/Bytes etc.. as **signed** numbers, it hit me with another curve ball and got me thinking if I really understand this treatment after all.

This is a piece of assembly code that is supposed to jump to an address if a condition is met (which indeed is met). PC just before the jump is `C838h` and then after condition check it is supposed to be: `C838h + FCh` (h = hex) which I thought would be treated as signed so the PC would jump backwards: `FCh = -4 in two's compliment negative number`. But To my surprise, java ADDED FCh to the PC making it ***incorrectly*** jump to `C934h` instead of back to `C834h`.

```
C832: LD B,04              06 0004 (PC=C834)
C834: LD (HL), A           77 9800 (PC=C835)
C835: INC L:00             2C 0001 (PC=C836)
C836: JR NZ, n             20 00FC (PC=C934)
```

I tested this in a java code and indeed the result was the same:

```
int a = 0xC838;
int b = 0xFC;
int result = a + b;
System.out.printf("%04X\n", result); //prints C934 (incorrect)
```

To fix this I had to cast FCh into a byte after checking if the first bit is 1, which it is: `11111100`

```
int a = 0xC838;
int b = (byte) 0xFC;
int result = a + b;
System.out.printf("%04X\n", result); //prints C834 (correct)
```

In short I guess my question is that I thought java would know that FCh is a negative number but that is not the case unless I cast it to a byte. Why? Sorry I know this question is asked many times and I seem to be asking it myself alot.

Comment: `0xfc` is 4 byte integer, so it is signed `0x000000fc`

Comment: Ok, but how can I tell java that this a negative number, which is what I want?

Comment: Let me rephrase that: How can I tell java to treat FC as a negative number?

Comment: Please look up `sign extension`. The short version is that for 0xfc to be a negative number in the first place, it would have to be in a signed *1-byte* type; then, when you assign the value to a wider signed type, it works automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0xfc` is a positive number. If you want a negative number, then write a negative number. `-0x4` would do just fine.

But if you want to apply this to non-constant data, you'll need to tell Java that you want it sign-extended in some way.
The core of the problem is that you have a 32-bit signed integer, but you want it treated like an 8-bit signed integer. The easiest way to achieve that would be to just use `byte` as you did above.

If you really don't want to write `byte`, you can write `(0xfc << 24) >> 24`:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a = 0xC838;
        int b = (0xfc << 24) >> 24;
        int result = a + b;
        System.out.printf("%04X\n", result);
    }
}
```

(The `24` derives from the difference of the sizes of `int` (32 bits) and `byte` (8 bits)).